# Advanced ADSL configuration for stability

Tags: adsl

I am renting a house in Spain with very shaky ADSL. I found the advanced settings in the "BHS RTA" modem but i havn't changed anything yet. Can someone with the know-how please advise if changing any of these will make the connection more stable? Stable 5mbps is better than the 15mbps dropping every 5 minutes that i have now.

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason that you cannot contact your provider, and obtain the *correct* settings?  Enabling both "T1.413" and "ADSL2+" (i.e. more than one mode) seems bizarre IMO.

Comment: @sawdust +1.  While you are speaking to your provider, ask them if interleaving is turned on - if not, ask if they can do it.  Interleaving  increases latency (but about 25ms) but also increases connection stability.  Its probably worthwhile if you are not a gamer.  Also discuss changing line profiles with them.  [ Note that I don't know anything about Spain - but this stuff is pretty common the world over ]

Comment: The reason i did not contact the provider is because i do not speak spanish. Google translate doesnt work very well over the phone.